# How to Export a current Azure App Service Certificate and import to a different subscription

Tags: azure, ssl, certificate, azure-web-app-service

I have Azure App Service Certificates created in a subscription. We are migrating all our applications including app services to a different subscription(which is not connected to the same Azure AD). I need to export the SSL cert and import to the new subscription as App Service Certificate. We need this as we have paid for the cert for 2 years so don't want to miss out on that. I have seen articles on how to export as .PFX file but how do you create a new Azure App Service Certificate in the new subscription using the .pfx file ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to export the SSL .pfx file. You can **move your App Service Certificate to a new subscription.** You could [do this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#a-nameuse-portal-by-using-azure-portal) on the Azure portal. If your App Service Certificate is bound to a web app, you must take some steps before moving the resources to a new subscription. Read this [similar scenario](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/8390#issuecomment-400225113).

> Delete the SSL binding and private certificate from the web app before
> moving the resources. The App Service Certificate doesn't need to be
> deleted, just the private certificate in the web app.

When moving resources to a new subscription, the following restrictions apply:

> All classic resources in the subscription must be moved in the same
> operation. The target subscription must not have any other classic
> resources. The move can only be requested through a separate REST API
> for classic moves. The standard Resource Manager move commands don't
> work when moving classic resources to a new subscription.

Read [App Service Certificate limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#app-service-certificate-limitations)

Comment: in this scenario I can 't do it given the subscription we are moving to is not connected to the same Azure AD...I edited the question so it is clear